# python matplotlib animation plot oop style implmentation problem

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, animation, plot

in the attached program I' m trying to receive some data through serial port and then record and plot them. I' m planning to use independent threads for read, record and plot. Read and record works fine but I couldn' t achieve to plot the coming data syncronously. I mean when a new data arrives I wanto to see it on the plot window. Also I want the plot window to open up when I start the system. After making many search and trials the second part of code did what I want and looks fine for me. This one can read and plot the data. The problem is I would like to implement it for my existing code which is designed in object oriented way but as you can see the plot program (second one) is in sequential manner. I couldn' t achieve to make it work in my excisting code. It would be grate if you can give me a hand.

note: The main code (first one) is a simplified version of an existing program.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit: I made following changes and I got "GUI object has no attribute 'update' " error.**

**import matplotlib.animation as anim -> ... as animation**

in DataPlotter function: **anim = self.anim.FuncAnimation(self.fig, update) -->**

**anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, update)**

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import Menu
from tkinter import messagebox as msg    
from threading import Thread
from threading import Timer
from queue import Queue
import time
from time import  sleep
import serial
from shutil import copyfile
import os    
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

#=====================================================
class GUI():
    def __init__(self):        

        self.root = tk.Tk()     
        self.port=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 115200)         
        self.root.title("Python GUI")      
        self.create_widgets()           
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.line1, = self.ax1.plot([], [], lw=1, marker = '*', linestyle='-', color='r')           

    def start(self):
        print("started")
        self.create_DataReader_Thread()
        self.create_DataRecord_Thread()
        self.create_DataPlotter_Thread()            

        day    = time.strftime('%d'); month  = time.strftime('%m')
        year   = time.strftime('%y'); hour   = time.strftime('%H')
        minute = time.strftime('%M')

        self.PC1 = open('Channel_1_'+day+month+year+'_'+hour+minute+'.txt', 'a')

    def stop(self):
        print("stopped")

    def reset(self):
        print("resetted")

    def quit_(self):
        self.root.quit()
        self.root.destroy()

    #===============================================================================

    def create_DataPlotter_Thread(self):
        self.run_thread = Thread(target=self.DataPlotter)
        self.run_thread.setDaemon(True)                     
        self.run_thread.start()

    def DataPlotter(self):
        idx=0
        while True:
            old_len=len(self.l1)
            if idx != old_len:
                idx+=1
                old_len=idx
                def update(i):
                    if len(self.l1)>1:
                        self.ax1.set_xlim(-5, max(x)+10)
                    if max(self.l1)>50:
                        self.ax1.set_ylim(-5, max(y)+10)        

                    line1.set_data(range(1,len(self.l1)), self.l1)
                    return self.line1
            anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.update)
            plt.show()          
    #===============================================================================

    def create_DataRecord_Thread(self):
        self.run_thread = Thread(target=self.DataRecorder)  
        self.run_thread.setDaemon(True)             

    def DataRecorder(self):
        idx=0
        while True:
            old_len=len(self.l1)
            if idx != old_len:
                print("new data received !")
                idx+=1
                old_len=idx
                self.PC1.write(str(self.cnt1[0]) + '\n'), self.PC1.seek(0)          
    #===============================================================================

    def create_DataReader_Thread(self):
        self.run_thread = Thread(target=self.DataReader)    
        self.run_thread.setDaemon(True)                     
        self.run_thread.start()

    def DataReader(self):

        self.l1=[]; self.l2=[]; self.l3=[]; self.l4=[]; self.l5=[]; self.l6=[]; self.l7=[]; self.l8=[]; self.l9=[];
        j=0

        while True:                         
            ans=self.port.read(28)              
            j+=1
            print('------------- ',j,' ------------------')
            for i in range(0,9):

                counter_bytes=ans[3*i+1:3*i+4]

                first  = bin(counter_bytes[0])[2:].zfill(8)
                second = bin(counter_bytes[1])[2:].zfill(8)
                third  = bin(counter_bytes[2])[2:].zfill(8)

                counter_bin = first + second + third
                counter_dec=int(counter_bin,2)

                if   i==0:  self.cnt1=counter_dec, self.l1.append(counter_dec)
                elif i==1:  self.cnt2=counter_dec, self.l2.append(counter_dec)
                elif i==2:  self.cnt3=counter_dec, self.l3.append(counter_dec)
                elif i==3:  self.cnt4=counter_dec, self.l4.append(counter_dec)
                elif i==4:  self.cnt5=counter_dec, self.l5.append(counter_dec)
                elif i==5:  self.cnt6=counter_dec, self.l6.append(counter_dec)
                elif i==6:  self.cnt7=counter_dec, self.l7.append(counter_dec)
                elif i==7:  self.cnt8=counter_dec, self.l8.append(counter_dec)
                elif i==8:  self.cnt9=counter_dec, self.l9.append(counter_dec)

            self.c1.set(self.cnt1[0]); self.c2.set(self.cnt2[0]); self.c3.set(self.cnt3[0]); self.c4.set(self.cnt4[0]); self.c5.set(self.cnt5[0]);
            self.c6.set(self.cnt6[0]); self.c7.set(self.cnt7[0]); self.c8.set(self.cnt8[0]); self.c9.set(self.cnt9[0]);    
    ################################################################################
    def create_widgets(self):

        tabControl = ttk.Notebook(self.root)            # Create Tab Control

        tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)                    # Create a tab 
        tabControl.add(tab1, text='CONTROL')            # Add the tab

        tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")          # Pack to make visible

        buttons_frame=ttk.Frame(tab1, relief="raised")
        buttons_frame.place(x=10, y=50, height=200, width=140)

        button1 = tk.Button(tab1, text='START', fg='black', font='none 15 bold', command=self.start)
        button2 = tk.Button(tab1, text='STOP' , fg='black', font='none 15 bold', command=self.stop)
        button1.place(x= 80 , y= 100, anchor='c')
        button2.place(x= 80 , y= 200, anchor='c')

        Channels_frame=ttk.Frame(tab1, relief="raised")
        Channels_frame.place(x=200, y=50, height=350, width=530)

        Channel_1 = ttk.Label(Channels_frame, text = 'Channel 1 : ')        
        Channel_2 = ttk.Label(Channels_frame, text = 'Channel 2 : ')        
        Channel_3 = ttk.Label(Channels_frame, text = 'Channel 3 : ')        
        Channel_4 = ttk.Label(Channels_frame, text = 'Channel 4 : ')        
        Channel_5 = ttk.Label(Channels_frame, text = 'Channel 5 : ')        
        Channel_6 = ttk.Label(Channels_frame, text = 'Channel 6 : ')        
        Channel_7 = ttk.Label(Channels_frame, text = 'Channel 7 : ')        
        Channel_8 = ttk.Label(Channels_frame, text = 'Channel 8 : ')        
        Channel_9 = ttk.Label(Channels_frame, text = 'Channel 9 : ')        

        Channel_1.place(x=100,  y=50 , anchor='c')
        Channel_2.place(x=280,  y=50 , anchor='c')
        Channel_3.place(x=430,  y=50 , anchor='c')
        Channel_4.place(x=100,  y=150, anchor='c')
        Channel_5.place(x=280,  y=150, anchor='c')
        Channel_6.place(x=430,  y=150, anchor='c')
        Channel_7.place(x=100,  y=250, anchor='c')
        Channel_8.place(x=280,  y=250, anchor='c')
        Channel_9.place(x=430,  y=250, anchor='c')

        Channel_1.config(font='none 12 bold')
        Channel_2.config(font='none 12 bold')
        Channel_3.config(font='none 12 bold')
        Channel_4.config(font='none 12 bold')
        Channel_5.config(font='none 12 bold')
        Channel_6.config(font='none 12 bold')
        Channel_7.config(font='none 12 bold')
        Channel_8.config(font='none 12 bold')
        Channel_9.config(font='none 12 bold')


        self.c1 = tk.IntVar()
        self.c2 = tk.IntVar()
        self.c3 = tk.IntVar()
        self.c4 = tk.IntVar()
        self.c5 = tk.IntVar()
        self.c6 = tk.IntVar()
        self.c7 = tk.IntVar()
        self.c8 = tk.IntVar()
        self.c9 = tk.IntVar()

        count_1 = ttk.Label(Channels_frame, textvariable=self.c1)   
        count_2 = ttk.Label(Channels_frame, textvariable=self.c2)   
        count_3 = ttk.Label(Channels_frame, textvariable=self.c3)
        count_4 = ttk.Label(Channels_frame, textvariable=self.c4)
        count_5 = ttk.Label(Channels_frame, textvariable=self.c5)
        count_6 = ttk.Label(Channels_frame, textvariable=self.c6)
        count_7 = ttk.Label(Channels_frame, textvariable=self.c7)
        count_8 = ttk.Label(Channels_frame, textvariable=self.c8)
        count_9 = ttk.Label(Channels_frame, textvariable=self.c9)

        count_1.place(x=100, y=90 , anchor='c')
        count_2.place(x=280, y=90 , anchor='c')
        count_3.place(x=430, y=90 , anchor='c')
        count_4.place(x=100, y=190, anchor='c')
        count_5.place(x=280, y=190, anchor='c')
        count_6.place(x=430, y=190, anchor='c')
        count_7.place(x=100, y=290, anchor='c')
        count_8.place(x=280, y=290, anchor='c')
        count_9.place(x=430, y=290, anchor='c')

        count_1.config(font='none 14 ')
        count_2.config(font='none 14 ')
        count_3.config(font='none 14 ')
        count_4.config(font='none 14 ')
        count_5.config(font='none 14 ')
        count_6.config(font='none 14 ')
        count_7.config(font='none 14 ')
        count_8.config(font='none 14 ')
        count_9.config(font='none 14 ')


        menubar = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=menubar)      

        exitmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        exitmenu.add_command(label="EXIT", command = self.quit_)
        menubar.add_cascade(label ="Quit", menu = exitmenu)         

gui = GUI()
gui.root.geometry('750x500')
gui.root.mainloop()
```

=============================================================

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib import animation
import time
from time import sleep
import serial

x=[]
y=[]

port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
line1, = ax1.plot([], [], lw=1, marker = '*', linestyle='-', color='r')

def update(i):
    while True:
        y.append(ord(port.read()))
        x.append(i)

        if len(x)>1:
            ax1.set_xlim(-5, max(x)+10)
        if max(y)>50:
            ax1.set_ylim(-5, max(y)+10)

        line1.set_data(x, y)
        return line1

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update)
plt.show()
```

Comment: How do the two code segments (which are separated by a line) relate to each other? I suppose your main problem is the `while True`, which will prevent the animation from actually running because that loop will never finish.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest First one is the main code and the second code is what I want to implement in the first one. Because it does what exactly I want, locating the new data point (if there is) to the graph (or replotting the final data set with new data points). Related to while loop, from idx=0 to  old_len=idx -> This part only identifes if there is new data or not. Then it will record it and hopefully plot it!